# Modify Class but Retain Class after Async

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the below style created, how this currently works is that I am using AngularJS to call an API which will return JSON. The response is true or false and based on the values from the database the class changes from white to green. Green represents that it needs to be completed. Once they are complete, they click the red button to clear it out. This all runs on a 5 second interval in Angular and checks the database and rewrites the $scope object.

Change request came in and they want to be able to click on the green items to check them off as they are complete, then click the red button. The problem, how can I get it to where I update the object without changing the already changed class that a user has completed?

[image]

Comment: So before the state of the green boxes was controlled by the server only and now the client can also control their state? Is the problem that you don't want to override the client changes within the next 5s update?

Comment: Correct, the changes from the client (users) need to stay the same after the 5s update, until the client (users) clear it.

Comment: But you don't want to update the server state when one of the boxes is clicked? So client and server state (with regard to the boxes) differ and this is intended?

Comment: Not at the moment no, I will eventually build this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no single truth about the state of the boxes anymore. One state is in the server and the client sees another state.

There is no other way than extending your model (the fields in your $scope) to keep track of the client changes. You could for example mark certain boxes as "locked" and prevent an update with the server values.

However, if your regular update just overwrites your model with a new set of values, you will have to write some code to update the existing model partially instead of overwriting it completely.